# Wrong list being returned in python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

```
def mainCall(nodeGroup):

    maxScore = -9999999
    maxPart = []
    tempPartition = []
    tempScore = 0.0

    for j in range(2, 1+nodes/2):

        nodeGroup = chooseInitPartition(j, nodeGroup)
        tempScore, tempPartition = runKL(edgeList, nodeGroup, rounds)
        print 'temp score', tempScore
        print 'temp part', tempPartition, "\n"
        if(maxScore < tempScore):
            maxScore = tempScore
            maxPart = tempPartition
            print "max score", maxScore
            print "maxpart", maxPart, "\n"

     print 'before ret max part', maxPart
     return maxScore, maxPart

finalScore, finalPartition = mainCall(nodeGroup)
```

I am having a problem with the above code. Everything seems fine till the `for` loop ends, but after that instead of printing the `maxPart` value at the line `print 'before ret max part'`, it prints the last value of `tempPartition` (both represent a list of numbers). 
The print statements confirm that the `if` condition is not satisfied every time, especially the last few runs in the loop. So I don't see how the value of `tempPartition` is being transferred to `maxPart`. Please help me with this. It is driving me crazy. I am sure I am missing something simple. Thanks!

EDIT:

Adding code for `runKL`

```
def runKL(edgeList, nodeGroup, rounds):

    nodeSwap = [0]*nodes
    maxLogLScore = 0.0
    edgeListLen = len(edgeList)

    networkPartitionStore = []
    logLScores = []

    #Reset count
    count = 0

    #Start main loop
    for i in range(rounds):
        #mark all vertices as unswapped
        for j in range(len(nodeSwap)):
            nodeSwap[j] = 0


        while(count < 100):
            #Choose one edge uniformly randomly
            randNum = random.uniform(0,1)
            edge = edgeList[int(math.floor(edgeListLen*randNum))]
            node1 = int(edge[0]) - 1
            node2 = int(edge[1]) - 1

            if((nodeGroup[node1] == nodeGroup[node2]) or (nodeSwap[node1] == 1) or (nodeSwap[node2] == 1)):
                count += 1
                continue
            else:
                #swap groups among nodes
                temp = nodeGroup[node1]
                nodeGroup[node1] = nodeGroup[node2]
                nodeGroup[node2] = temp

                #mark vertices as swapped
                nodeSwap[node1] = 1
                nodeSwap[node2] = 1

                #calculate likelihood
                logLScore = logLikelihood(edgeList, nodeGroup)
                logLScores.append(logLScore)

                #store network
                networkPartitionStore.append(nodeGroup)

                #reset count value
                count = 0

        #end while loop

        #Choose the index of the maximum likelihood score
        maxLogLScore = max(logLScores)
        index = logLScores.index(maxLogLScore)
        #print 'max score', modularityScores[index]

        #Choose the corresponding network partition i.e. the way the groups have been assigned to the nodes
        nodeGroup = networkPartitionStore[index]

        #Reset partition storage list and modularity scores
        networkPartitionStore = []
        logLScores = []

        #Store initial network partition structure and modularity score. 
        networkPartitionStore.append(nodeGroup)
        logLScores.append(maxLogLScore)

    return maxLogLScore, nodeGroup
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you say

```
maxPart = tempPartition
```

you are not creating a copy of `tempPartition` but you are making the `maxPart` also to point to the same list that `tempPartition` points to. To really make a copy, you can use slicing notation like this

```
maxPart[:] = tempPartition
```

or

```
maxPart = tempPartition[:]
```

The difference between `maxPart[:] = tempPartition` and `maxPart = tempPartition[:]` is that the former mutates the `maxPart` and copies all the values from `tempPartition` to `maxPart` and latter creates a new list with a copy of all the data in `tempPartition` and makes the `maxPart` points to the newly created list.

Comment: `maxPart[:] = tempPartition` or `maxPart = tempPartition[:]` ?

Comment: @Maxime They both work. Please check the explanation I added in the answer.

Comment: @thefourtheye Thank you very much for your answer. I used `maxPart[:] = tempPartition` and it worked.

Comment: I'd say that the fix described in this answer shouldn't be necessary. The real bug is in the `runKL` function, which is returning the same list over and over (with different values in it each time, I assume). I'd fix that instead, rather than working around it.

Comment: @thefourtheye: Well, none of the code we can see mutates the list, so it must be getting mutated somehow by the part we can't see. I'm just guessing that it happens in `runKL`, since that's where we get the list from.

Comment: @Blckknght Thats a possibility but even if the `if(maxScore < tempScore):` is met once, they both point to the same list. So, thats also a possibility, right?

Comment: @thefourtheye: Um, sure. But that shouldn't matter. `tempPartition` gets rebound on each pass through the loop on the line `tempScore, tempPartition = runKL(edgeList, nodeGroup, rounds)`. It doesn't ever get mutated by the loop's code. So, it should be fine to simply hold a reference to it in `maxPart`.

Comment: @Blckknght Oh yeah. You got a point. Lets ask the OP for `runKL` code.

Comment: @FieryDragon87 Could you please show us `runKL`'s code as well? We want to make sure that the problem has really been fixed or not.

Comment: @Blckknght @thefourtheye - Like you two have discussed, I guess the `runKL` is returning the same list but with different values. 
In this situation all I want is to keep a track of the `maxPart` that corresponds to `maxScore`. So the fix suggested earlier works well for my current situation. But I would like to know if I am making some fundamental mistake. I am pretty inexperienced at coding in Python. Thanks!